# Save and remember UIElement values after segue without using core data?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uislider, data-persistence

I have a mini-workout application, the root is a `UITableViewController` and each cell `segues` to a specific TVC that has its own specific settings denoted by UISliders and UISegmented Controls (As shown by the image).

Of course when I navigate back to the root controller and back again to the specific cell workout, the UIElements forget the previously entered values.

However setting up Entities and Attributes does not seem like the most efficient way to remember the UISettings? Should I use `encoder decoder`, write to a file?

There must be an efficient way to do this. Thanks.

[image: Too many UI Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an object call it anything you like, example `UIValues`. 
Let this object have the properties that you want to save:

```
@property (assign) CGFloat pushupsToday;

....
```

Create this object and have a strong reference to it. For example in your `appDelegate` or your `RootViewController`.

let your viewControllers share this object when you are trying to push new viewController example `newViewController.uiValues = self.uiValues.`

If you want to save this value to disc, then you have to make to encode and decode values.

Comment: Because I have multple workout routines, would you say encoding and decoding is a better way to persist all these UIValues than setting up attributes in Core Data?

Comment: I don't think passing the data up and back is the best way

Comment: That depends on the amount of data that you want to save, if you have a lot of them, then of course coreData is the choice. But any way you need an object to save the values and pass them to viewControllers to update there UI states. @CescSergey

Comment: yeah I expect to add more workout routines with more specific UISettings, core data is the way to go thanks.